# how to change list presentation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How can I change my list  in a Bigger example

From:

```
b = rdd_two.rdd.map(list)
for new_rrd_list in b.collect():
   print(new_rrd_list)
```

output look like this:

```
['lunar', 2.862386971953217] 
['satellite', 2.7074850119674734] 
['needs', 3.7074850119674734]  
['fuel', 3.230363757247811]  
['regular', 4.008515007631455]  
['orbit', 2.646787171613862]  
['corrections', 3.5313937529117925]
```

To:

```
print(wanted_list)
```

output:

```
    [{'lunar': 2.862386971953217, 
      'satellite': 2.7074850119674734,
      'needs': 3.7074850119674734,
      'fuel': 3.230363757247811,
      'regular': 4.008515007631455,
      'orbit': 2.646787171613862,
      'corrections': 3.5313937529117925}
    ]
```

Comment: What does `print(mylist)` actually print?  It's missing opening and closing `[]` that would indicate a list -- is it actually a list, or is it a string?  And what's with the backslashes?

Comment: my list is made by :                                                                                                         
b = rdd_two.rdd.map(list)
  
# display the data in b with collect method
for new_rrd_list in b.collect():
    print(new_rrd_list)

Comment: And one call to `print(new_rrd_list)` prints multiple lines of output like that?  If it does, `new_rrd_list` isn't a list, it's a string.  Or do you have code in a loop that's printing multiple lists, and you want to combine all those lists into a dict?  It's hard to tell when the code is in a comment and all smushed onto one line -- maybe you should include the code as part of the question.

Comment: it prints ['lunar', 2.862386971953217]
['satellite', 2.7074850119674734]
['needs', 3.7074850119674734]
['fuel', 3.230363757247811]
['regular', 4.008515007631455]
['orbit', 2.646787171613862]
['corrections', 3.5313937529117925]
['fuel', 3.230363757247811]
['runs', 3.5313937529117925]
['crash', 4.008515007631455]
['within', 2.9671223224732297]
['months', 3.230363757247811]

Comment: What prints that -- one call to `print()` like in your question, or a `print()` in a loop that's printing different lists?  If it's a loop, *include the code for the loop in your question* instead of saying in your question that this is a single list you need to transform.  Those are very different situations.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example is `mylist = [["a", 0], ["b", 1]]`? If so you might simply want to convert it to a dictionary.

Comment: so my problem was is that i wanted to change the rdd to a list, as the one in the 2nd output of the question. so i found a code which imma add now in the question that prints me the 'String' that i thought it was a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop doesn't give you a *single* list, it iterates over everything in `b.collect()` and produces a sequence of different lists:

```
for new_rrd_list in b.collect():
   print(new_rrd_list)
```

To get your `wanted_list` (a list containing a single dictionary whose keys and values come from pairs yielded by `b.collect()`), you want to instead turn that iterable into a dict, and then put that dict in a list:

```
wanted_list = [dict(b.collect())]
```